# Positioning logo's of different sizes inside rectanlge

Tags: adobe-illustrator, interface-design, layout, affinity-designer

I have a bunch of logos of different proportions that need to be positioned inside a rectangle. I can do this by hand so the layout is not as chaotic as it would be with a center/fit placement.

Is there any way to automate this layout?

[image: This is what I want to achieve:]

Using Affinity Designer or Illustrator.

Comment: What program are you using?

Comment: @WELZ I'm using affinity designer/illustrator

Comment: @WELZ the images are meant for use in an app, so I could do it programmatically if there is a way, but that would probably be a questin for stackoverflow I figured :/

Comment: In the "zalando lounge" logo, you have chosen to include the orange shape in the centering, but in the "MENO pro" logo you have only used the "MENO" part for centering. Visually I understand why, but if you want a programmed solution you will need to find the geometrical logic behind your two different choices.

Comment: @wolff that logic is what I'm looking for I guess so perhapse this is more of a question for stackoverflow

Comment: Maybe. But I meant that you as a designer should try to make the rules, in words or diagrams, so a programmer could translate that logic to code. Why is the orange dot taken into account when the "pro" square isn't? Why is "zalando" vertically centered on the x-height when "MENO" is centered on the capitals? Also, are the logos images or vector paths? How should the program analyze the shape and give different meaning to the parts? It just seems like a hard task - not the code but the rules behind. [I answer a related question here.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/91092/84899)