# Is there a formula/method to center objects when software centering appears visually "off"?

Tags: design-principles, alignment, layout

Imagine a group of objects, type and elements. If I use software to "align on centers", *visually* the topmost element *appears* off center due to the *weight* of other elements. It's not off center. It's properly inline. This is merely a visual oddity.

In the image below, grey objects are type elements. Using software alignment, all horizontal groupings within the layout are aligned "on center" to each other. However the rule/banner across the top, to me, *seems* off-center. I've double and triple checked, it is indeed on-center.

[image]

I can "eyeball" that top element to try and make it *feel* more centered:

[image]

There's no math or precision to the placement of that top grey box in the image directly above. It's completely my "gut" feeling about alignment to try and visually balance things more in my perception. While it **is** now off-center, my brain doesn't perceive it as off-center, unlike the first image.

So, my question...

**Is there some precise methodology to visually align elements on center when *actual* alignment appears unbalanced?** Or is it always a matter of simply "eyeballing" things?

<sub>Also willing to accept that my eyes are "wonky" and the top image is fine.</sub>

---

Somewhat irrelevant, but in this case I'm using Adobe Illustrator. This issue is slightly more apparent when viewing the actual type. Unfortunately, I can't share the actual type.

---

Comment: Related: [Aligning letters “Wrong” appears more “Right”](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/57620/23061)

Comment: Eyeballing is an art/skill. And as a veteran designer I believe you have a great eye for it! While a formula could approximate this result with the right training and inputs, to do so generically for all forms of alignment no matter the size/color/etc and make the result the most appealing to humans I think is close to impossible.

Comment: @ZachSaucier .. that's an answer `:)` Maybe not a "here's how" answer, but an answer. Actually I may delete this because it's kind of a duplicate of your link to a large degree unless someone responds with something new.

Comment: Its not impossible that there could be a formula

Comment: Maybe [quadtrees](https://blog.mapbox.com/a-new-algorithm-for-finding-a-visual-center-of-a-polygon-7c77e6492fbc)? There's a link for JS library that uses this method in the article. This is not exactly what you ask, but still an interesting read %)

Comment: Very interesting. I tried to answer a [somewhat similar question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/91075/how-to-achieve-balance-when-objects-are-asymmetrical/91092#91092) some years ago. It's still just about eye-balling, but I'm trying to show how the "center of mass" method shouldn't be applied when it only moves the object a tiny bit. I'm wondering if a script/formula could ever make that decision. It all depends a lot on the shapes in play. Round letters are more forgiving than letters with vertical lines in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually are some formulas. For example: Photographers know that a image does not look centered  if they are entirely centered in the frame and have [determined formulaic methods for this](http://www.russellcottrell.com/photo/centering.htm).

However if we calculate the center of mass of the gray areas (center of mass is where a physical object is balanced. Most humans know approximately where that is):

```
from scipy import ndimage
import imageio

for img in ("scott_optical.png", "tru_center.png"):
  balanced = imageio.imread(img )[:,:,3]
  bin_balanced = (balanced > 128) * 1
  mass = ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(bin_balanced)
  print (img ,mass[1],mass[1]/bin_balanced.shape[1])
```

You can run above code [HERE](https://repl.it/repls/OrnateFairBases) as well as view the images used. Then we get that:

```
scott_optical.png 351.39763320288984 0.504157292974017
tru_center.png 352.65615675542125 0.5059629221742056
```

indeed scott's version is more balanced in terms of center of mass. The last number of line is the fractional center of mass of shaded pixels which should be as close to 0.5 as possible. But be careful the images should match exact same dimensions and have same padding. Off course you may get better results with your actual imagery.

I'm not saying center of mass is the only thing to do but it certainly is a part of the problem. Just saying there is some scientific basis to claim that its more balanced.

Comment: Interesting....

Comment: @Scott added some other musings

Answer (score 1):

Formula, no. Method.. maybe.

Generally, I will personally avoid getting into a situation where math alignment looks off. Either one of your options will look odd to some degree, depending on the person looking at it.

However, if all other options have been explored and it really must be done this way, nope, math alignment will not work. You need to look at the overall composition and come up with the best optically balanced compromise.

In your particular case, where the left side of that bottom left box is kind of very close to the top box, I would also consider 2 other options:

1. left align the top box to the big box below, or
2. keep the top box math centered, but adjust all the elements below so these 2 boxes share the same left edge

Anything that works to keep these 2 boxes sticking to a single guideline to the left. Yes, you will end up with a slight mathematical imbalance, but nobody will notice that without any actual measurement.

[image]

Comment: Believe it or not, it is exactly that slight misalignment of things at the top which seem to balance everything. The "overhang" of the small box seems to cause a "tilt" to the left which is visually counter-acted by the large box below it. Odd, I know. I do generally agree though, aligning to other elements when possible is a viable way to try and find balance.